# Self-signed *.dev cert untrusted using Firefox 59 on Ubuntu

Tags: ssl, firefox, self-signed, hsts

I am using Firefox 59.0.1 on Ubuntu and I am seeing the following error when accessing my development environment which is behind a self-signed SSL cert.

> Your connection is not secure
>
> The owner of crmpicco.dev has configured their website improperly. To
>   protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected
>   to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> Learn more…
>
> Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious
>   sites
>
> crmpicco.dev uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

I have added "crmpicco.dev" to security.tls.insecure_fallback_hosts and set security.enterprise_roots.enabled to true, restarted Firefox but this has had no effect.

I know Chrome has their "badidea"/"thisisnotsafe" workaround, which I know isn't ideal but it at least works - whereas I am yet to find a Firefox equivalent.

What is the solution for this? Do I need to generate new self-signed certs even although the cert I have is from Feb 2018.

I have tried the numerous questions on here and Mozilla support to no effect.

Comment: I'm guessing Brand Domains like *`*.test`* and *`*.dev`* are pinned though a [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), like [libpsl](https://github.com/rockdaboot/libpsl). I think you need to run your own CA. A self-signed won't do. Also see [Trouble with local HTTPS certificate for *.test domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49085903/608639).

Comment: @jww So do you think this is specific to `.test` and `.dev` TLD? My domain and TLD are entirely arbitrary so if I change that to something random like `.crmpicco` should that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top level domain *.dev is [owned by Google](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/dev.html). For [some time already](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/29/google_dev_network/) there has been a pre-configured HSTS policy in Chrome which made it impossible to use self-signed certificates for this domain. Firefox recently added such policy too so you get the same behavior now.

There are several ways to deal with this. The best way is to not use any currently public or future public top level domains for your private purpose. By using such domains you risk to getting in conflict with usage policies enforced by the domain owner, like enforcing HSTS in case of *.dev. Also, it might even cause [security problems](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA16-144A).  Instead use either domains you actually own or use top level domains which are reserved for internal and test use, like *.test, *.invalid or *.example.

If you really want to use *.dev internally (again, bad idea) you can do it by following the policy of this domain: don't use a self-signed certificate but use a certificate issued by a CA trusted by your browser. This means creating your own CA, adding it as trusted to the browser and then issue the certificates you want by this CA. But again, using public domains you don't own (no matter if top-level or not) is a receipt for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. There are other threads suggesting that `.test` is not available for use. Is there a list of published TLD reserved for internal uses that won't fall foul of the same restrictions?

Comment: @crmpicco: see [RFC 2606 - Reserved Top Level DNS Names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) and its update [RFC 6761 - Special-Use Domain Names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761).

Comment: What are your thoughts on this as a solution? https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12580865

Comment: @crmpicco: The idea covered in the link you refer to is to use a subdomain from a domain actually owned. This is already covered by *"..use either domains you actually own.."* in my answer.

Comment: Have you got a reference for "Firefox recently added such policy too"? I'd like to see if I'm also affected by this (and provide some… feedback).

Comment: @Calrion: according to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1204477 it is since firefox 59.0b7.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information. I added a `ServerAlias` to my Apache config for `crmpicco.localhost` and I can now use HTTPS locally on any browser.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  This has been driving me batty for weeks. Just to add my my 2¢ - I have an entry in my hosts file for a development server.  The entry is 'myserver-dev', and that one also appears to have this cert issue.  I also have 'myserver-qa' deploying the exact same web app with the same self-signed cert, and that one has no trouble.  Also if I go directly to the IP instead of the hostname it works.  So it appears Firefox is identifying the '.dev' domain even if the hostname just ends in 'dev'.